# Как написать строку в конце, чтобы вывелась рамка из точек?

Tags: python

```
def kvadrat(w, N):
  
    for i in range(1):
        print(w*".", sep="", end="\n") 
       
        for j in range(N):
            print(1*'.', (w-2)*" ", 1*'.', sep="", end="\n")
            
            for m in range(j+1, -1):
                print(w*".", sep="", end="") 

kvadrat(8, 5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def q(a,b):
    for i in range(b):
        if i==0 or i==b-1:
            print('*'*a)

        else:
            print('*'+' '*(a-2)+'*')

q(10,10)
```

---

```
**********
*        *
*        *
*        *
*        *
*        *
*        *
*        *
*        *
**********
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def rectangle(a, b):
    print('\n'.join(['*' * a] + ['*' + ' ' * (a - 2) + '*' * (a > 1)] * (b - 2) + ['*' * a * (b > 1)]))
```